# What is need of Count in the following bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

```
echo 'Enter no'
read x
n=2
while [ $n -le $x ]
do
i=2
count=1

while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
if [ `expr $n % $i` -eq 0 ]
then
count=0
break
fi
i=`expr $i + 1`
done

if [ $count -eq 1 ]
then
echo "$n is Prime"
fi

n=`expr $n + 1`
done
```

Comment: It stores the result of the calculation which determines if a number is prime. Not a very meaningful name, isPrime for example would be better.

Comment: Using a language with very limited arithmetic capabilities for finding primes is not a brilliant idea.

Comment: You don't need `expr`; check the bash man page for "Arithmetic Expansion". E.g. `i=$((i + 1))`. Also, see http://shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really a counter, just a flag.
If any modulus operation returned a 0, then the value is not prime. The flag is set so that after the inner loop completes, you can see that the value was not prime.

If the value never was divisible, then the counter flag was never reset to 0, so you know it is prime.